# Django filter ListView by user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have `@required_login` decorator in my views, but I need my `ListView` to show only objects related to the currently logged in user.

I am trying:

```
class NdaList(ListView):
    form_class = NonDisclosureForm
    template_name = 'nda/nda_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return NonDisclosure.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

but it gives me a `Cannot query "charles": Must be "Profile" instance.`

My models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="profile", verbose_name="user")
...

class NonDisclosure(Timestamp):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="nda", verbose_name="user")
...
```

I have tried everything I can, but with my still limited knowledge of Django, I am out of ideas.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: post your settings.py file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick solution:

```
        return NonDisclosure.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user)
```

additional:

I think it's better to change the `user` field name in `NonDisclosure`, since actually the field is point to a `Profile` instance instead of `User`.

```
class NonDisclosure(Timestamp):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="nda", verbose_name="user")
```

and also your query statement change to:

```
return NonDisclosure.objects.filter(profile__user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: But user is of type `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is also a User-like model. after all, the additional part is just for avoiding misleading.

Comment: ya, you have to pass  AUTH_USER_MODEL's instance not string.

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to discuss this...I can't believe how much time I wasted on this :)  It also makes sense to change my my `NonDisclosure` `user` to `Profile` - since user is set in `Profile`.  Thank you for the suggestion.